# Chained Where causing Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I have a problem with Entity Framework Plus. Ctx works, ctx2 works but when I execute ctx3 I get : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong ? GetQueryableContext has been reduced to _context.Set.

Thanks.

```
var ctx = await GetQueryableContext(request);
ctx = ctx.Where(x => x.DepotNo >= request.DepotNo);
ctx.Update(x => new Order() { LorryLoadingListPrinted = 1111 });

var ctx2 = await GetQueryableContext(request);
ctx2 = ctx2.Where(x => x.DepotNo <= request.DepotNo);
ctx2.Update(x => new Order() { LorryLoadingListPrinted = 2222 });

var ctx3 = await GetQueryableContext(request);
ctx3 = ctx3.Where(x => x.DepotNo >= request.DepotNo).Where(x => x.DepotNo <= request.DepotNo);
ctx3.Update(x => new Order() { LorryLoadingListPrinted = 3333 });
```

Comment: What is the value of `ctx3` in the debugger?

Comment: It looks like your two chained `.Where(...)` calls could be just replaced by a single one: `ctx3.Where(x => x.DepotNo == request.DepotNo)`

Comment: @Volodymyr yes it could be, but want this way for te question. Typically 'GetQueryanleContext' returnes quite a lot of chained where based on a request but as I was getting the problem therefore I wanted to narrow it down. The below code also works:             var ctx4 = await GetQueryableContext(request);
            ctx4 = ctx4.Where(x => x.DepotNo <= request.DepotNo && x.DepotNo >= request.DepotNo);
            ctx4.Update(x => new Order() { LorryLoadingListPrinted = 2222 });

Comment: `.Where()` never returns `null` unless the LINQ provider has a bug in its implementation; it's supposed to always return a non-`null` `IEnumerable` (even if that enumerable may contain no elements). Either that's the case, or something obscure like `request.DepotNo` changing or throwing inbetween the calls is happening (or, conceivably but improbably, somehow the query execution results in `null` records being produced, though that should also be a bug). Take a harder look at the stack trace to see where the NRE is being generated.

Comment: @JeroenMostert before posting here I've reduced the code down to what you see so nothing happening to DepotNo.